# How can I evaluate the connectedness of my nodes?

Tags: algorithm, math, graph

I've got a space that has nodes that are all interconnected, based on a "similarity score".  I would like to determine how "connected" a node is with the others.

My purpose is to find nodes that are poorly connected to make sure that the backlink from the other node is prioritized.

Perhaps an example would help.

I've got a web page that links to my other pages based on a similarity score.  Suppose I have the pages: A, B, C, ...

A has a backlink from every other page, so it's very well connected.  It also has links to all my other pages (each line in the graph is essentially bidirectional).
B only has 1 backlink, from A.
C has a link from A and D.

I would like to make sure that the A->B link is prioritized over the A->C link (even if the similarity score between C and A is higher than B and A).

In short, I would like to evaluate which nodes are least and best connected, so that I can mangle the results to my means.

I believe this is Graph Connectedness, but I'm at a loss to develop a (simple) algorithm that will help me here.  Simply counting the backlinks to a node may be a starting point -- but then how do I take the next step, which is to properly weight the links on the original node (A, in the example above)?

Comment: I don't really understand your problem, can't you just count the number b(p) of backlinks for each page p, and give each link the weight 1/b(target of the link) ?

Comment: Ooh, your comment is great as well.  For some reason I just couldn't mentally understand that the weight inversion is what I need, especially when I multiply that inverted backlink weight by my similarity score.  This is a great first step before I dive into centrality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Centrality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrality) is a measure of "...the relative importance of a vertex within the graph (for example, how important a person is within a social network, or, in the theory of space syntax, how important a room is within a building or how well-used a road is within an urban network)."

(from Wikipedia, of course).

As an interesting (and practical) application of this concept, someone has mapped the [most connected artcile on Wikipedia](http://www.netsoc.tcd.ie/~mu/wiki/). It turns out to be [2007](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2007). That same page offers a discussion of the basic algorithm and even some sample code.

Some other potentially useful metrics can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_network#Metrics_.28measures.29_in_social_network_analysis).